# How to create new variable at the end of each loop iteration in R

Tags: r, loops, dataframe, for-loop

I am trying to create a variable that is a function of 4 other variables. I have the following code:

```
set.seed(123)
iter <- 1000
group <- c('A','B','C','D','E','F')
for (i in group) {
  df <- df1[df1$group == i,]
  x_ <- vector(mode="numeric", length=1000)
  assign(eval(paste0("X_", i)), globalenv())   #This is the issue

  a <- rnorm(iter, mean=df$a, sd=df$sea)
  b <- rnorm(iter, mean=df$b, sd=df$seb)
  c <- rnorm(iter, mean=df$c, sd=df$sec)
  z <- rnorm(iter, mean=df$zbar, sd=df$se_z)

  X_[i] = (a + c*(z-df$zbar))/(-b)
}
```

I am unable to create a unique group-specific variable (e.g. X_A, X_B, ...) and I am unsure why the -assign( )- function is not working properly. The dataframe `df1` has 6 rows (one for each group) and then the number of columns is equal to the number of variables plus a string variable for group. I am not trying to append this new variables `X_[i]` to the dataset I am just trying to place it in the global environment. I believe the issue lies in my assigning the placement of the variable, but it isn't generating a numeric variable X.

`df1` is a dataframe with 6 observations of 9 variables containing `a, sea, b, seb, c, sec, zbar, se_z`. These are just the means and standard deviations of a, b, c, and z, respectively. The 9th variable is `group` which contains A, B, ..., F. When I use the code `df <-df1[df1$group == i,]` I am trying to create a unique `X` variable for each group entity.

Comment: Can you precise what is `df1` and `crop` ? and also provide a reproducible example of `df1` if `df1` is a dataframe

Comment: I have updated the question, thank you for pointing this out

Comment: This is a bad design patter in R. Rather than pasting data in to names of variables, store values in a named list. This makes things much, much easier to work with in R. `get()/assign()` should generally be avoided

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
dynamicVariableName <- paste0("X_", i)
assign(dynamicVariableName, (a + c*(z-df$zbar))/(-b))
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively to the answer from @ErrorJordan, you can write your loop like that:

```r
set.seed(123)
iter <- 1000
group <- c('A','B','C','D','E','F')
for(i in group)
{
  df <- df1[df1$group == i,]

  a <- rnorm(iter, mean=df$a, sd=df$sea)
  b <- rnorm(iter, mean=df$b, sd=df$seb)
  c <- rnorm(iter, mean=df$c, sd=df$sec)
  z <- rnorm(iter, mean=df$zbar, sd=df$se_z)

  X <- (a + c*(z-df$zbar))/(-b)
  assign(paste0("X_",i),X,.GlobalEnv)
}
```

As suggested by @MrFlick, you can also stored your data into a list, to do so you can just modify your loop to get:

```r
set.seed(123)
iter <- 1000
group <- c('A','B','C','D','E','F')  
X = vector("list",length(group))
names(X) = group
for(i in 1:length(group))
{
  df <- df1[df1$group == group[i],]    
  a <- rnorm(iter, mean=df$a, sd=df$sea)
  b <- rnorm(iter, mean=df$b, sd=df$seb)
  c <- rnorm(iter, mean=df$c, sd=df$sec)
  z <- rnorm(iter, mean=df$zbar, sd=df$se_z)

  X[[i]] <- (a + c*(z-df$zbar))/(-b)
}
```

**df1 dataframe**

```r
df1 = data.frame(a = c(1:6),
                 b = c(1:6),
                 c = c(1:6),
                 zbar = c(1:6),
                 sea = rep(1,6),
                 seb = rep(1,6),
                 sec = rep(1,6),
                 se_z = rep(1,6),
                 group = group)
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a little hard to parse what you want to do, but I'm assuming it's something like

> for each value in `group` make an object (in the global env) called `X_A`, `X_B`, ...
>
> for each one of those objects, assign it the value `(a + c*(z-df$zbar))/(-b)`

I think this should do that for you:

```
set.seed(123)
group <- c('A','B','C','D','E','F')
for (i in group) {
  df <- df1[df1$group == i,]

  a <- rnorm(iter, mean=df$a, sd=df$sea)
  b <- rnorm(iter, mean=df$b, sd=df$seb)
  c <- rnorm(iter, mean=df$c, sd=df$sec)
  z <- rnorm(iter, mean=df$zbar, sd=df$se_z)

  assign(paste0("X_", i), (a + c*(z-df$zbar))/(-b), globalenv())
}
```

Note that in the code example you gave, the command `iter <- 1000` has no effect, and the command `x_ <- vector(mode="numeric", length=1000)` also has no effect. By that I mean, you make those objects, but never subsequently use them in any further computation. If those commands should do something meaningful I'll need your help in explaining their intended purpose.

Comment: Iter is used at the beginning of each random variable generation as the number of observations, the vector one is not used though thanks for pointing that out